# Unable to import airflow package

Tags: python-import, airflow

Using VS code when attempting to import airflow I am getting this error

> Import "airflow.modules" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

Per class instructions I have pip with the following:

`pip3 install apache-airflow==2.1.0 --constraint https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marclamberti/742efaef5b2d94f44666b0aec020be7c/raw/21c88601337250b6fd93f1adceb55282fb07b7ed/constraint.txt`

Screenshot of error:

[image: unable to import airflow screensho]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow addressed this in Python 3.8 https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/12859

pip install apache-airflow

installed the latest apache airflow (2.3.2), which resolved the issue.

My environment is wsl ubuntu running python 3.8.10